# Excel leave existing date in cell (calendar VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, date, calendar

I am using VBA calendar to input dates in my workbook. I have added code to my worksheet to call calendar on double click of cell. So basically when I double click cell in range I get calendar form, where I pick up the date and then it is inserted in double clicked cell. The only problem is that after closing my calendar form my cell gets selected and I see formula inside my cell. How I can make it close my calendar form without selecting cell after it?
I have used this calendar:
https://trevoreyre.com/portfolio/excel-datepicker/

Code to call calendar form by double clicking cell in range:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)


  Dim xRg As Object


    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E7:F187")) Is Nothing Then dateVariable = CalendarForm.GetDate
  if datevariable=0 then
   exit sub
  else
  For Each xRg In Selection.Cells
  xRg.Value = dateVariable
  Next xRg
End if
'datevariable=0


    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try, this.  It seems that you can select another cell in the code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Target.Offset(1, 0)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E7:F187")) Is Nothing Then datevariable = CalendarForm.GetDate
    If datevariable = 0 Then
        rng.Select
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Target.value = datevariable
        rng.Select
    End If

End Sub
```